# Apache POI 4: XSSF equivalent of HSSF DocumentSummary

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, xls

I am updating code that saves tables to xls to support xlsx. To add information about the columns in the table to the xls file, this is done:

```
protected DocumentSummaryInformation writeMappings(final WorkbenchTemplate wbt)
{
    DocumentSummaryInformation dsi = PropertySetFactory.newDocumentSummaryInformation();
    CustomProperties cps = new CustomProperties();
    List<WorkbenchTemplateMappingItem> wbmis = new ArrayList<WorkbenchTemplateMappingItem>(wbt.getWorkbenchTemplateMappingItems());
     for (WorkbenchTemplateMappingItem wbmi : wbmis)
    {
        cps.put(ConfigureXLS.POIFS_COL_KEY_PREFIX + wbmi.getViewOrder(),
                wbmi.getCaption()
                + "\t" + wbmi.getTableName() 
                + "\t" + wbmi.getFieldName()
                + "\t" + wbmi.getXCoord() 
                + "\t" + wbmi.getYCoord()
                + "\t" + wbmi.getCaption()
                + "\t" + wbmi.getFieldType()
                + "\t" + wbmi.getMetaData()
        );
    }
    dsi.setCustomProperties(cps);
    return dsi;
}
```

The result is then added to the xls file, after the table data has been saved, like this:

```
            if (mappings != null) {
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
                POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
                is.close();
                mappings.write(poifs.getRoot(), DocumentSummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                poifs.writeFilesystem(fos);
                fos.close();
            }
```

How can this be accomplished with an xlsx file?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html#getProperties-- and https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLProperties.CustomProperties.html ?